# How to call PHP function inside HTML Email

Tags: php

So i want to send email which have table that should been filled with info from database. I have PHP function that generate table with info from database, and im not sure how i can call it inside $message string properly or is it even possible:

```
$message =
"
   <table>
      myFunction($id);
   </table>
";
```

Now in html it should make whole table and later i send it using mail() function. But i cant get it to call myFunction($id) and generate data?

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with an email, you're just trying to build a string.  While variable names are evaluated in double-quoted strings, functions are not.  So just evaluate the function directly and concatenate the results into the string:

```
$message =
"
   <table>
      " . myFunction($id) . "
   </table>
";
```

Or, perhaps clearer without the whitespace:

```
$message = "<table>" . myFunction($id) . "</table>";
```

Comment: Yes i know, i already tried that, but empty table appear, instead when i run that php page, i get that response echo-ed on php page not in email

Comment: @АцаРусија: Well, according to the code you're asking about in the question you had not tried that.  As for an "empty table", what have you confirmed in your debugging?  What does `myFunction` do and how have you validated that it's returning the data you expect?  If you're successfully building a string with no data between the `<table>` tags then it sounds like `myFunction` isn't returning anything, so outside the scope of this question you'll need to begin investigating that separate issue.

Comment: myFunction generate <tr> with <td> inside filled from database. When i run this php script, response from database is echo-ed on page but its not in mail that i send

Comment: @АцаРусија: Then it sounds like your function is echoing data to the output instead of returning that data.  If your function isn't doing what you want it to do then I recommend examining and correcting your function.  The code in the question only *calls* the function, it has no control over what that function actually does.

Comment: Yeah maybe its because in myFunction i echo every <td> thats why it appear on php page but not in mail, what should i do instead of echoing it?

Comment: @АцаРусија: You can use the “return” keyword to return a value from a function: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

Answer (score 0):

In myFunction i was echo-ing `<tr>` and `<td>`. That was problem, thanks [@David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/328193/david) for pointing that out!

I solved it by instead of echo-ing result, i pushed results to array and then returned that array.